# Does Vatican II Church acknowledge the statement of Pope Francis saying he is the Bishop Dressed in White?

Tags: catholicism

Francis in Fatima: "I am the bishop dressed in white."

Now, in the official missal of his visit to Fatima today and tomorrow, in the Prayer specially written for this day, Francis identifies himself as the "bishop dressed in white":

Hail Holy Queen, blessed Virgin of Fatima, Lady of the Immaculate Heart, refuge and path that guides to God! Pilgrim of the Light that we receive from your hands, I thank God the Father that, at all times and places, acts in human history; pilgrim of the Peace that you announce here, I praise Christ, our peace, and for the world I ask for concord among all peoples; pilgrim of the Hope which the Spirit encourages, I want to be prophet and messenger so as to wash the feet of all at the same table that unites us.

Hail Mother of Mercy, Lady of the white robe! At this place where one hundred years ago you showed all the designs of our God's mercy, I look upon your robe of light and, as bishop dressed in white ***(como bispo vestido de branco)***, I remember all those who, robed in baptismal white, want to live in God and pray the mysteries of Christ to attain peace.
[Francis in Fatima: "I am the bishop dressed in white."](https://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2017/05/francis-in-fatima-i-am-bishop-dressed.html)

Does the Vatican II acknowledge Pope Francis statement that he is the Bishop Dressed in White in light of his statement which is included in the prayer?

Comment: I don't know Portuguese well enough to say for sure, but the phrase you quoted and the English translation seem to admit the interpretation that he is **a** bishop dressed in white but not necessarily **the** specific bishop dressed in white described in the Fatima prophecy.

Comment: I believe that Pope John Paul II believed he was the bishop dressed in white, but can not remember where.

Comment: @KenGraham As far as I know the prophecy said that there will be an attempt to murder a bishop dressed in white but the bishop will survive. There was an attempt to murder John Paul II and he survived. In this context he said that he believes that the prophecy was about that murder attempt.

Comment: It seems to be the interpretation of the Portuguese that Pope Francis said something such as: like a bishop in white and not the bishop dressed in white. This prayer was not pronounced during the Mass of May 13.2017, but the day before. [Source](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/liturgy/libretti/2017/20170512-13_messale-fatima.pdf)

Comment: This question makes no sense to me - anyone got a link to something that explains the background?

Comment: @curiousdannii See these sources [here](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20000626_message-fatima_en.html) and [here](https://www.catholicculture.org/news/features/index.cfm?id=20583).

Answer (score 2):

**Does Vatican II Church acknowledge the statement of Pope Francis saying he is *thee* Bishop Dressed in White?**

The short answer is **no**.

Before going on let us look at the exact text in question from the [Vatican](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/liturgy/libretti/2017/20170512-13_messale-fatima.pdf), while here is a translation in English:

> Hail Holy Queen, blessed Virgin of Fatima, Lady of the Immaculate Heart, refuge and path that guides to God! Pilgrim of the Light that we receive from your hands, I thank God the Father that, at all times and places, acts in human history; pilgrim of the Peace that you announce here, I praise Christ, our peace, and for the world I ask for concord among all peoples; pilgrim of the Hope which the Spirit encourages, I want to be prophet and messenger so as to wash the feet of all at the same table that unites us.
>
> Hail Mother of Mercy, Lady of the white robe! At this place where one hundred years ago you showed all the designs of our God's mercy, I look upon your robe of light and, as [a] bishop dressed in white [como bispo vestido de branco], I remember all those who, robed in baptismal white, want to live in God and pray the mysteries of Christ to attain peace. - [Francis in Fatima: "I am the bishop dressed in white."](https://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2017/05/francis-in-fatima-i-am-bishop-dressed.html)

First of all, this prayer is not from the Missal as stated as the article in question. In fact it is simply part of the liturgical program at Fatima over the two day interval of May 12 and 13, 2017. The quoted prayer was recited by His holiness Pope Francis the day prior to the Canonization of Francisco Marto and Jacinta Marto.

The prayer in English simply states that the pope came **as a** bishop dressed in white, but not as **thee** bishop dressed in white as predicted in the [final prophecies of Fatima](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20000626_message-fatima_en.html).

Here is an English translation of the third part of the secret of Fatima which deals with the bishop dressed in white:

> I write in obedience to you, my God, who command me to do so through his Excellency the Bishop of Leiria and through your Most Holy Mother and mine. After the two parts which I have already explained, at the left of Our Lady and a little above, we saw an Angel with a flaming sword in his left hand; flashing, it gave out flames that looked as though they would set the world on fire; but they died out in contact with the splendor that Our Lady radiated towards him from her right hand: pointing to the earth with his right hand, the Angel cried out in a loud voice: "Penance, Penance, Penance!" And we saw in an immense light that is God--something similar to how people appear in a mirror when they pass in front of it--a Bishop dressed in White--we had the impression that it was the Holy Father. Other Bishops, Priests, men and women Religious going up a steep mountain, at the top of which there was a big Cross of rough-hewn trunks as of a cork-tree with the bark; before reaching there the Holy Father passed through a big city half in ruins and half trembling with halting step, afflicted with pain and sorrow, he prayed for the souls of the corpses he met on his way; having reached the top of the mountain, on his knees at the foot of the big Cross he was killed by a group of soldiers who fired bullets and arrows at him, and in the same way there died one after another the other Bishops, Priests, men and women Religious, and various lay people of different ranks and positions. Beneath the two arms of the Cross there were two Angels each with a crystal aspergilium in his hand, in which they gathered up the blood of the Martyrs and with it sprinkled the souls that were making their way to God. - [Full Text of the Third Secret Revealed October 11, 2001](https://www.catholicculture.org/news/features/index.cfm?id=20583)

Pope John Pau II believed that he was the bishop in white. Pope St. John Paul II survived an assassination attempt. That assassination attempt took place at St. Peter's Square on May 13, 1981, the anniversary of the [Apparitions of Fatima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_F%C3%A1tima).

[image: John Paul II was shot at Fatima in 1981 and recovered]

[John Paul II was shot at Fatima in 1981 and recovered](https://www.traditioninaction.org/HotTopics/g46_Secret_2.htm)

For more information see [*The Message of Fatima*](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20000626_message-fatima_en.html) **(Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith**).

Whether the Vatican interpretation of the prophecy and Pope St. John Paul II is correct or not is beyond the scope of this question. Let it suffice to state that there exists yet another prophecy about a bishop in white: [Our Lady of Quito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Good_Success), Ecuador (1611).

Comment: @jongricafort This question / answer isn't about what or who the "bishop dressed in white" is – it's asking whether the Vatican has acknowledged a particular statement.  Please don't attempt to discuss side issues – focus on the question and answer itself.

Answer (score -2):

*Does Vatican II Church acknowledge the statement of Pope Francis saying he is the Bishop Dressed in White?*

**The short answer is YES!**, *but only silently* as revealing the True Fatima Secrets who is the Bishop Dressed in White will compromise the War with Satan and his forces of darkness. It's enough to see that *Pope BXVI had expanded the Petrine Ministry and had chosen the title "Emeritus" not renouncing the "munus"* to become the personal Prayer Warrior of Pope Francis the Bishop Dressed in White and a Great Intercessor for the Universal Church embracing the meaning of his chosen name Holy Father St.Benedict.The Vatican had openly acknowledged that ***Pope Francis is a Luminous Pope meaning Pope Clothe with the Light of Christ.***

[image]

> ... ***And we saw in an immense light that is God***--something similar to how people appear in a mirror when they pass in front of it--**a Bishop dressed in White**--we had the impression that it was the Holy Father. ***Other Bishops, Priests, men and women Religious going up a steep mountain***, at the top of which there was a big Cross of rough-hewn trunks as of a cork-tree with the bark; before reaching there the Holy Father passed through a big city half in ruins and half trembling with halting step, afflicted with pain and sorrow, he prayed for the souls of the corpses he met on his way; having reached the top of the mountain, on his knees at the foot of the big Cross he was killed by a group of soldiers who fired bullets and arrows at him, and in the same way there died one after another the other Bishops, Priests, men and women Religious, and various lay people of different ranks and positions...***(Sis.Lucia's visions at Fatima)***

We can see that Sis.Lucia described first an ***immense LIGHT from God*** and the Bishop Dressed in White together with  Bishops, Priests, men and women Religious. The description of Dressed in White if we relate to the wordings of the Missal does not pertain to a literal Pope's white clothing but rather a ***"spiritual clothe"*** a ***Robe of Light.***

*Let's ponder the wording of the [liturgical program](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/liturgy/libretti/2017/20170512-13_messale-fatima.pdf) at Fatima (May 12/13, 2017) about the Light;*

> Hail Holy Queen, blessed Virgin of Fatima, Lady of the Immaculate Heart, refuge and path that guides to God! ***Pilgrim of the Light*** that we receive from your hands, I thank God the Father that, at all times and places, acts in human history; pilgrim of the Peace that you announce here, I praise Christ, our peace, and for the world I ask for concord among all peoples; pilgrim of the Hope which the Spirit encourages, I want to be prophet and messenger so as to wash the feet of all at the same table that unites us.

The first paragraph of the prayer mentioned the words ***" Pilgrim of the Light that we receive from your hands,.."***
This would mean that those in pilgrims or having their christian journey was associated with the Light and had received a clothing of Light from the Hands of Mary. Could this be the New Rosary, ***the Mystery of the Light***?

*And moving on...*

> Hail Mother of Mercy, ***Lady of the white robe!*** At this place where one hundred years ago you showed all the designs of our God's mercy, ***I look upon your robe of light and, as bishop dressed in white*** [como bispo vestido de branco], I remember all those who, ***robed in baptismal white,*** want to live in God and pray the mysteries of Christ to attain peace. - **Francis in Fatima: "I am the bishop dressed in white."**

The phrase ***"Hail Mother of Mercy, Lady of the white robe!"*** this coincides with **Revelation12:1** as ***the Woman Clothe with the Sun.***

The next phrases stated ***"I look upon your robe of light*** and, as ***bishop dressed in white*** [como bispo vestido de branco], I remember all those who, ***robed in baptismal white,*** want to live in God and pray the mysteries of Christ to attain peace.

We can see that the composed prayer speaks about spiritual clothing not a literal Pope Dressed in White but a ***Bishop Dressed with the Robe of Light*** and supported with followers who are also clothe with the Robe of Light bestowed on their Baptism.And the important thing is they are praying the "mysteries of Christ". The Pilgrim of Light was praying the Rosary given in their hands by Mary, ***again could this be the New Luminous Mystery the Mystery of the Light?***

The Bishop Dressed in White is together with the Marian faithful as ***St.Montfort*** described this warrior as the ***Apostles of the Last Times*** totally united to the Pope and fully consecrated to the Immaculate Heart of Mary. This Remnant Marian group whose leader is the Pope is where the Immaculate Heart of Mary will Triumph.

As Our Lady had clearly promised Her Blue Mantle of protection to the Holy Father;

> "She will accompany the Holy Father until the end because he will greatly suffer from persecutions." (Our Lady promised at Faitma & La Salette)

Who are those persecutors of the Holy Father, the Bishop Dressed in White?

The visions of Sis.Lucia above said the group of armies possessed a weapon ***"group of soldiers who fired bullets and arrows"***. The weapons are bullets and arrows, *really arrows?*

We are not talking of real bullet and arrows here, but the arrows describe in **Ehpesians6:12-ff** as we are not fighting flesh and blood here.

> **Ephesians 6:12-17 New International Version (NIV)**
>   12 For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the powers of this dark world and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms. 13 Therefore put on the full armor of God, so that when the day of evil comes, you may be able to stand your ground, and after you have done everything, to stand. 14 Stand firm then, with the belt of truth buckled around your waist, with the breastplate of righteousness in place, 15 and with your feet fitted with the readiness that comes from the gospel of peace. 16 ***In addition to all this, take up the shield of faith, with which you can extinguish all the flaming arrows of the evil one.*** 17 Take the helmet of salvation and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God.

The weapon of the evil ones are ***arrows or flaming arrows*** and ou***r shield is our Faith.*** The Vatican II Church where the *smoke of satan* fires a lot of *arrows of Dubia/Doubt* to sow divisions and confusions to the Church. But, we have to remember the vision of Pope Leo XIII in 1884 as satan asked for more power to destroy His Church. So, what is the additional power that God granted to satan and his demons in the form of** "bullet"**. When we talked about** "bullet" **it means it is more powerful that ***"arrows"*** so a shield of faith can be penetrated, The bullet means it will explodes, and the first bullet that was fired signalling that the Great Accuser was UNCHAINED having the weapon of bullets in his hand is the *"Original Testimony of Ab.Vigano"*. The *testimony of Ab.Vigano is a bullet* that explodes into a scandal where the shield of faith cannot withstand the attack. We are in the end times as St. John Paul II the Great described this moment as Final Confrontation.

God has allowed and granted satan and his demons to fire ***"bullet"*** in the form of ***"uncovering the sins of the Bishops & Priest"*** even confessed sins. The power that God granted to satan in 1884 can kill the soul of the Clergy meaning they will lost their priesthood. *A priest scandalized by demons is a dead priest,* and a Bishop scandalized is even much worse as the damage is greater, the Diocese suffers death.

This is what it meant in the vision of Sis.Lucia. So with the meaning of ***"Robe of Light" and "bullets & arrows"*** defined we know that St.John Paul II assassination is not what Sis.Lucia had seen in the vision. The Holy Father the Bishop Dressed in White pointed not to St. John Paul II.

The Bishop Dressed in White is perfectly described by the vision of one of the seer not Sis. Lucia but Jacinta, seeing the Holy Father in a big house.

> ‘I don’t know how it happened but I saw the Holy Father in a very big house, kneeling by a table, with his head buried in his hands, and he was weeping. ***Outside the house, there were many people. Some of them were throwing stones, others were cursing him and using bad language.*** Poor Holy Father, we must pray very much for him.’”

The question is who is among the Holy Father beginning from St.John Paul II then Pope Emeritus Benedict XVI and now Pope Francis had suffer tremendous persecutions?

Pope Francis is being fired with both ***"arrows & bullets"*** to sow Dubia in His Teachings and attack his dignity thru fake news on the homosexual scandal accusing him of cover-ups.

Pope Francis knew that in these kind of attack the ***"shield of faith"*** is not enough, in order not to be hit by the bullets of scandalizing one's dignity, Pope Francis reminded all the Bishops & Priest with these words.

> **"Sanctity is stronger than scandal"** (Pope Francis)

Pope Francis emphasizing *Silence & Conversion* as the key to defeat the Great Accuser and ***by living a life of humility,simplicity and transparency*** a faithful can be **Clothe with the Light of Christ.**

St.John Paul II is not the Bishop Dressed in White but he is the one who *gave us the Robe of Light* our weapon in the Age of Darkness which is the Mystery of the Light.

**"The LIGHT shines in the darkness but the darkness has not overcome it."**(John1:5)

Pope Francis had acknowledge indirectly that He has no problem accepting what is written in the Missal Prayer pointing to a Bishop Robe with the Light of Christ but certainly and definitely ***Pope Francis is Clothe with the Light of Christ.***
Our Lady has prepared the priestly vocation of Pope Francis with no errors and past sins so that in the end times even if the Great Accuser is UNCHAINED the *"Light of Christ which is the the Robe of Pope Francis"* cannot be penetrated even by the bullets.

**In closing, to answer the question "Does Vatican II Church acknowledge the statement of Pope Francis saying he is the Bishop Dressed in White?**

***Answer***

The Vatican had acknowledged that title called to Pope Francis as the **"Luminous Pope"** by living a life of humility, simplicity and transparency it's a way of imitating the public life of Jesus Christ. Pope Francis controversial teaching was likened to Jesus encountering the Pharisees who embraced traditions but never practiced it themselves. 
Since, *St.John Paul II describes the Final Confrontation as War in the End Times* it would be wise and prudent for the Vatican not to shout out that *Pope Francis with so many indications is the Bishop Dressed in White.*

The letter of resignation of Pope Benedict XVI reveals the power of Silence or Contemplative aspect of Papacy. Pope Francis as the Bishop Dressed in White had implore "Silence" after reflecting in one of his homily in Santa Marta that the Great Accuser is unchained.Pope Emeritus BXVI had received the Wisdom of God to ***expand the Petrine Ministry*** to prepare the Church for battle with the forces of darkness. As in order to win the Final Confrontation with Satan, the Vatican II Church needs the powerful presence of Jesus.
Pope Emeritus BXVI united in prayer with Pope Francis as both have universal power bestowed on a Supreme Pontiff can claim the Power of Jesus in Matthew Gospel that is emanating from the Chair of Peter.

> ***Truly I tell you, whatever you bind on earth will be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be loosed in heaven. 19Again, I tell you truly that if two of you on the earth agree about anything you ask for, it will be done for you by My Father in heaven. 20For where two or three gather together in My name, there am I with them.”***

*Satan the Great Accuser* may be left unchained now *having wolves in sheep clothing* (Bishops & Cardinals) among his ranks inside Vatican and *having numerous packed of wild dogs* (church critics & enemies) attacking the Church and the Priesthood but it has no match with a Church having ***Two Great Popes both Master in the Art of Spiritual War*** using the ***power of Silence or Contemplative Prayer.***

> **"The Lord will fight for you, and you have only jto be silent.”**(Exodus14:14)

Comment: I think you could improve this answer by being less rambley and take out the last 3 paragraphs starting with "but personally I believe"  because answers on this site aren't supposed to contain personal opinion.

Comment: @Peter Turner i remove the word "but personally" and just pointed to the content of the letter of resignation of Pope BXVI stating his new mission which is the Power of Silence/CCC2717. We need wisdom to weave the action of Pope BXVI and tied it up with his own prophecy saying the church will be reduced to a small poor church but a more pious one.Pope Francis had embraced this vision stating "how I wish the Church becomes poor and for the poor".Both Pope agreed in the direction the Church must embraced.CCC675 thats why Matthew18:19 fits as the Two are in united as one in Silence/CCC2717.

Comment: I edited in the official Vatican liturgical program for the occasion of the Canonization of Francisco Marto and Jacinta Marto. The prayers are from the liturgy held on the 12th of May and are not from the Missal as you claimed.

Comment: @Ken Graham thanks numerous blogsite tell it was from Missal '"I am the bishop dressed in white." - Pope Francis
Page 9, Missal of the visit to Fatima, May 12-13, 2017. https://lesfemmes-thetruth.blogspot.com/2017/05/i-am-bishop-dressed-in-white-pope.html and the other from https://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2017/05/francis-in-fatima-i-am-bishop-dressed.html Liturgical or missal the focus here is the prayer whose central theme is "Robe of Light" from Pope to Pilgrim of Light. it speaks about Mary giving a Clothing of Light from praying the mysteries of Christ. Luminous Mystery & Luminous Pope.

Comment: @Ken Graham "A missal is a liturgical book containing all instructions and texts necessary for the celebration of Mass throughout the year."https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missal

Comment: The liturgy in question was not a Mass!